# returning data from model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

now how to get data back in View from model ?
my code:

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("register","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="submitForm"})) 
   {

     <div>
      <i>@Html.Label("Name:")</i>
         @Html.TextBox("txtboxName")
     </div>

     <div>
      <i>@Html.Label("Email:")</i>
         @Html.TextBox("txtboxEmail")
     </div>

     <div>  
      <i>@Html.Label("Password:")</i>
         @Html.Password("txtboxPassword")
     </div>

     <div>  
      <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
   </div>


}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult register(string command, FormCollection formData ) 
        {
            if (command == "Submit") 
            {
                var name  = formData["txtboxName"];
                var email = formData["txtboxEmail"];
                var pwd   = formData["txtboxPassword"];

                database db = new database();
                db.connectDB(name, email, pwd);
                ViewBag.Message = email;


            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
     namespace LoginSys.Models
    {
        public class database
        {
            public void connectDB(String name, String email, String pwd)
            {
                String conStr = "Data Source=HUNAIN-PC;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=abc123!@#";

                sqlconnection sqlCon = new sqlconnection(conStr);
                string comm = "insert into tblRegister  values('"+name+"','"+email+"','"+pwd+"')";
                sqlcommand sqlCom = new sqlcom(comm, con);

                try
                {
                 sqlCon.Open();
                 sqlCon.executeNonQuery();
                }
                 catch(exception exc)
                 {
                  //code
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                  con.close();
                 }


            }
        }
    }
```

now how to return NO OF ROWS EFFECTED BY EXECUTENONQUERY statement or suppose any thing to return ? simple words and please help me in this approach, will use advance techniques later.

Comment: use [ViewBag](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx)

Comment: First achieve returning `NO OF ROWS EFFECTED BY EXECUTENONQUERY` from `connectDB` function. Currently the function doesn't return anything

Comment: done,

String returnValue =  db.connectDB(name, email, pwd, conStr);

Comment: Your code has SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return something, you can use SqlParameter ParameterDirection.Output like this:

```
SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand(connStr); // connection string
cc.CommandText = "insert into tblRegister (Name, Email, Pwd) values (@name, @email, @pwd); select @result = @@identity";
cc.AddWithValue("@name", name);
cc.AddWithValue("@email", email);
cc.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);
cc.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
cc.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cc.ExecuteNonQuery();

// returs identity key
int id = (int)cc.Parameters["@result"].Value;
```

Then you can return this id from your function, but you have to modify it's prototype:

```
public int connectDB(String name, String email, String pwd) // changed void to int
{
    // ...
    return id;
}
```

Then you can simply put this value to ViewBag, or use other ways to pass it to your view:

```
            database db = new database();
            ViewBag.Id = db.connectDB(name, email, pwd);
            ViewBag.Message = email;
```

If you use ViewBag, you can access it in your view with `@ViewBag.Id`

Comment: great but how to do this part 

 catch(exception exc)
                 {
                  //code
                 }

how to return caught exception to the view since it doesn't work with response.write

Comment: try and catch exception in your controller. On exception, just return another view like "return View("Error")";